# Unable to cast object of type 'masterpage' to type 'master'

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Im getting this error, very rare cases, not able to trace where is wrong going?
Error Msg:
 "Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.femaster_master' to type 'FEMaster'."

The same page happens to work fine when reupload via FTP, looks strage

Please do help on this.

Comment: did you rename the masterpage? do you have two masterpages called femaster_master and FEMaster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a masterpage called femaster_master try to exclude this one from the project you 
should be able to see where it is (incorrectly) referenced.

Answer (score 0):

This bug started when I upgraded my development machine.

The fix is stupid...but the problem went away...Simply wrap it in a try catch block.  I had it in a property.

Never seen it again.

```
Private Function MyMasterPage() As SalesMasterPage
    Try
        Return CType(Page.Master, SalesMasterPage)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'log error
    End Try
End Function
```